# How to select from MySQL where colmun is type text and data is json

Tags: mysql, json, select, text, casting

Magento 2 table 'sales_order_payment' have column 'additional_information' which is in data type 'text'. Now data inside this field I see that is json (but as string - text)

```
{"raw_details_info":{"CustomerFirstname":"Mary",...
```

How can I select this as json?

I have try this. First I create view where I cast this column as json:

```
CREATE VIEW JSONTEST as SELECT cast(additional_information as json) as test FROM sales_order_payment;
```

Then I try to select this as json:

```
SELECT test->>'$.CustomerFirstname' from JSONTEST
```

But result is null. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path must start from the top of the document.

```
SELECT test->>'$.raw_details_info.CustomerFirstname' ...
```

Also the JSON stored in your TEXT column must be valid JSON, or else your cast will return an error. This is an advantage of the JSON data type in MySQL 5.7 and later, because it will require the content to be valid JSON.

Comment: you are time saver. Thank you very much